# Method call error inside received email body

Tags: python, django

I am sending an automated email through the system and when it arrives in the body of the email all the methods are there, except the str(self.total_mes_pagar) method that appears the following line"`<bound method Mensalista.total_mes_pagar of <Mensalista">`
I am very new to python and would appreciate all the help and patience with me, because I am almost going crazy with this problem

models.py

```
class Veiculo(models.Model):
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    ano = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="2018")
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    proprietario = models.ForeignKey(
        Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, )
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.modelo) + ' - ' + str(self.placa)

class Mensalista(models.Model):
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        blank=False)
    inicio = models.DateField(("Início"), default=datetime.date.today)
    validade = models.DateField(("Validade"), blank=False, )
    valor_mes = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
    pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)


@property
    def email(self):
        return self.pessoa.email

    def mensal(self):
        return math.ceil((self.validade - self.inicio).total_seconds() / 
            86400)

    def total_mes(self):
        return math.ceil(self.mensal() // 30)

    def total_mes_pagar(self):
        return self.valor_mes * self.total_mes()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.veiculo) + ' - ' + str(self.inicio)

    def send_email(self):
        if self.pago == 'Sim':
            assunto = 'Comprovante pagamento Estacione Aqui 24 Horas'
            mensagem = 'Obrigado por utilizar o Estacione Aqui 24 horas. 
                Ativação do estacionamento dia :  ' + str(self.inicio) + 
                    'Com validade até o dia   ' + str(
                         self.validade) + '  Confirmamos o pagamento do 
                              valor de: ' + str(self.total_mes_pagar) + '   
                                  E aguardamos seu retorno '
            recipient_list = [self.email]

            send_mail(
                assunto,
                mensagem,
                'estacioneaqui24@gmail.com',
                [recipient_list],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

Comment: Please share full error traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are not calling your method.

```
str(self.total_mes_pagar())
```

Comment: same mistake my friend

Comment: Perfect my friend

Answer (score 0):

`valor_mes` is a field. `total_mes_pagar` is a method. Methods need to be called by using `()` in the ends.

If you were using templates, which you are not, you would not need to call it directly. In your case, you're building the text inside your `send_email` method. In this case, it does need to be explicitely called, here:

```
def send_email(self):
        if self.pago == 'Sim':
            assunto = 'Comprovante pagamento Estacione Aqui 24 Horas'
            mensagem = 'Obrigado por utilizar o Estacione Aqui 24 horas. 
                Ativação do estacionamento dia :  ' + str(self.inicio) + 
                    'Com validade até o dia   ' + str(
                         self.validade) + '  Confirmamos o pagamento do 
                              valor de: ' + str(self.total_mes_pagar()) + '
                                  E aguardamos seu retorno '
            recipient_list = [self.email]

```
        send_mail(
            assunto,
            mensagem,
            'estacioneaqui24@gmail.com',
            [recipient_list],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```